Number of real roots in a semi-bounded interval of a univariate polynomial
The Sturm-Habicht sequence of a univariate polynomial allows to get the number of all real roots of this polynomial as well as the number of real roots of this polynomial in a bounded interval (see e.g. this paper). What about the number of real roots in a "semi-bounded" interval (of form $(a, +\infty)$ or $(-\infty, b)$)?

I've found the answer on Wikipedia.
To apply the procedure to an interval $(a, b)$, one has to compute the values of the Sturm-Habicht polynomials at $a$ and at $b$. Here is how to deal with the unbounded intervals:

if $b = +\infty$, one takes the leading coefficient of each Sturm-Habicht polynomial;
if $a = -\infty$, one takes either the leading coefficient or the opposite of the leading coefficient, according to the parity of the degree of the Sturm-Habicht polynomial.

That seems to work (I implemented the procedure), although the theorems stated on Wikipedia are different than the ones stated in the paper I linked, e.g. the Wikipedia theorems make the assumption that the polynomial is square-free while there's no such assumption in the paper. But they use a different definition of the Sturm-Habicht sequence: they use division remainders while the theorems of the paper use subresultants.
